# Golang - Get a pointer to a field of a struct through an interface

Tags: pointers, reflection, go

I'm at a very early stage of understanding interfaces in Go. I'm writing some logical simulations and have something like the following code (I heavily simplify here):

Please see the comments for my question:

```
type LogicNode struct {
    Input   *bool
    Output   *bool
    Operator string
    Next     Node
}

func (n *LogicNode) Run() {
    // do some stuff here
    n.Next.Run()
}

type Node interface {
    Run()
}

func main() {

    nodes := make([]Node, 1000)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        n := LogicNode{
            //assign values etc.
        }
        nodes[i] = &n
    }

    for i, node := range nodes {
        // I need to access LogicNode's Output pointer here, as a *bool.
        // so I can set the same address to other Node's Input thereby "connecting" them.
        // but I could only get something like this:

        x := reflect.ValueOf(node).Elem().FieldByName("Output")

        // which is <*bool Value>
        // I couldn't find a way to set a new *bool to the underlying (LogicNode) Struct's Input or Output..
    }
}
```

The reason I'm using interfaces is because there are other node types FloatNode MathNode etc. which have different fields, but they implement their own run method.

I've successfully used Value's SetString or SetBool methods, but can't set a pointer there... Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just convert Node to LogicNode and access fields directly?

Comment: Good Suggestion, that was the other solution. If there will be quite many types and not so many fields, it's not obvious, which is the better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Set](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) generic version to update the field value:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type LogicNode struct {
    Input   *bool
    Output   *bool
    Operator string
    Next     Node
}

func (n *LogicNode) Run() {
    // do some stuff here
    // n.Next.Run()
    fmt.Printf("LogicNode.Input = %v (%v)\n", *n.Input, n.Input)
}

type Node interface {
    Run()
}

func main() {
    input := false
    input2 := true
    fmt.Printf("Input1 = %v (%v)\n", input, &input)
    fmt.Printf("Input2 = %v (%v)\n", input2, &input2)
    var node Node = &LogicNode{Input: &input} // Remember, interfaces are pointers
    node.Run()
    x := reflect.ValueOf(node).Elem().FieldByName("Input")
    x.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&input2))
    node.Run()
}
```

Outputs:

```
Input1 = false (0x10500168)
Input2 = true (0x10500170)
LogicNode.Input = false (0x10500168)
LogicNode.Input = true (0x10500170)
```

Playground [here](http://play.golang.org/p/XDhAnvfMe2).

Comment: Pure happiness :) Muchas Gracias!